Plotting column with NaN values using GeoPandas
I have code that runs through a GeoJSON file and plots columns from that file one by one to show the user the costs of optimisation. It ran fine until it came across a column of just nan values.
I did some looking into this and discovered that the GeoPandas (v0.14.4) plotting file first creates a list of which values are nan:
nan_idx = np.asarray(pd.isna(values), dtype="bool")

then it resets the values variable to contain all the values that are not nan:
values = cat.codes[~nan_idx]

and then it fills nans with a placeholder so that it can properly plot them:
for n in np.where(nan_idx)[0]:
    values = np.insert(values, n, values[0])

and this is where the issue is! As the column just contains nans, I get an IndexError from values[0] as it's now empty. This was reconfirmed by changing one value to a float and it worked perfectly; plotting the nans as missing values.
Can anyone tell me if there is another way to plot columns containing all nan values or if this issue has been developed in newer versions of GeoPandas? It's important to show that the values are all "missing values", as that will just show that that specific column is not feasible.
All the above code is found in the geopandas/plotting.py file for GeoPandas (v0.14.4) and happens within the plot() function in the snippet of my code below (where name is the column name and hexagons refer to a Geopandas gdf):
import geopandas as gpd
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_and_save(crs, name, legend_kwds, output_folder, figsize=(10,5), legend=True, cmap='viridis_r', 
             missing_kwds={"color": "lightgrey", "label": "Missing values",},
             bbox_inches="tight",
             ):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
    ax = plt.axes(projection=crs)
    ax.set_axis_off()

    hexagons.to_crs(crs.proj4_init).plot(
        ax=ax,
        column = name,
        legend = legend,
        cmap = cmap,
        legend_kwds = legend_kwds,
        missing_kwds = missing_kwds,
    )

    ax.set_title(name)
    fig.savefig(output_folder + f"/{name}.png", bbox_inches=bbox_inches)
    plt.close()

hexagons = gpd.read_file("results/hexfile.geojson")

hexagon_bounds = hexagons.geometry.bounds    
min_lon, min_lat = hexagon_bounds[['minx','miny']].min()
max_lon, max_lat = hexagon_bounds[['maxx','maxy']].max()

central_lon = (min_lon + max_lon)/2
central_lat = (min_lat + max_lat)/2

crs = ccrs.Orthographic(central_longitude = central_lon, central_latitude= central_lat)

output_folder = 'plots/results'

plot_and_save(crs, 'pipeline transport costs', {'label':'pipeline cost [euros/kg]'}, output_folder) 

Here is how a plot looks when it has values for everything:

And here is a plot which only has one value, I would like to have a plot that is just fully greyed out:


Make it easier for us to reproduce please - can you include the relevant import statements in your code snippet.

Thank you @ user2856 and @ Bera for your comments, I have edited this now and I hope it's clearer. Please let me know if there's anything more that I can do.
